# Как на Stack Overflow относятся к теоретическим вопросам?

Tags: обсуждение

Как вы понимаете, 99,9% вопросов на SO (ruSO в частности) - это вопросы плана

**Как правильно сделать это на C++?**
**Ошибка в команде Linux**

Т. е. скажем так, это вопросы практического плана. У человека есть реальная проблема, реальная задача, которую ему надо решить.

Однако вот лично я задавал на ruSO вопросы и теоретического плана. Вот только из последних: [Как устроено микроядро?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1421107/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%be%d1%8f%d0%b4%d1%80%d0%be), [Как запускается fs_mgr в Android?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1420108/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-fs-mgr-%d0%b2-android). И таких вопросов у меня здесь на деле немало. Т.е., у меня и не стоит какая-то задача как таковая, мне просто интересно, как устроена та или иная программа, как именно она выполняет свою работу - как в плане алгоритмическом (по типу: *вот есть /init. Вначале, он загружает политику SELinux. Затем он парсит fstab и монтирует разделы с него...*), так и плане кода (*исходники находятся тут, там есть файл init.cpp. За монтирование fstab отвечает функция mount_fstab()*) - с приведением этого самого кода и пояснениями к нему. Если с сугубо алгоритмическим принципом все понятно - такое может быть описано в документации, или же каких-то тематических статьях, то вот с кодом все гораздо сложнее.

Потому что исходный код далеко не всегда легко читать - и дело даже не в навыке чтения чужого кода как таковом. Вот не знаю, кому как, а я при чтении исходников Magisk в своё время себе голову жёстко поломал, так ничего конкретно из них не поняв. Вот, меня конкретно сейчас волнует вопрос, как Magisk пересобирает политику SELinux. Естественно, подсознательно я уже ожидаю, что есть файл `native/jni/init/selinux.hpp`, в нем есть функция `rebuild_policy()`, а уже там я все пойму. Но нет, я реально из исходного кода ничего не понял. Нет, я все понимаю - код пишет каждый так, как ему удобнее. Но вот лично мне такое читать особенно трудно.

Конечно, логика подсказывает, что можно посмотреть соответствующие библиотеки/заголовки (в моём случае - libselinux). Но и там я [пока] ничего подобного и близко не нашёл.

Но здесь хотя бы примерно понятно, куда копать. Как я с `magic mount` от Magisk намучался - это целая история. Лишь в какой-то статье я нашёл, что это по сути bind-mount. Но у меня были вопросы по tmpfs - как она монтируется в /system, не перекрывая системные файлы? А вот этого я не нашёл нигде. Вообще. Я пробовал проводить подобный эксперимент с разделом /vendor. Как только я ни пытался получить тот же результат. В какой-то момент я, откровенно отчаявшись, пошёл на ruSO и даже enSO со своим вопросом. Ответов не получал от слова совсем - но и минусовать мои вопросы, к счастью, никто не стал. Конечно, в конечно итоге, экспериментируя со своим телефоном, я разобрался, как это работает. Пытливость и практика дали свой результат.

И вот меня с недавних пор волнует такой вопрос. А вот как к ТЕОРЕТИЧЕСКИМ вопросам относятся на StackOverflow? Т.е. когда человек не имеет конкретную проблему, а просто хочет разобраться, как та или иная программа устроена? Согласитесь, что далеко не всем легко читать исходный код, даже при вполне хороших знаниях, а документация/статья (если вторая вообще есть) банально не всегда может дать ответ на твой вопрос.

Comment: все ок, если вопрос соответствует правилам.

Comment: Да нормально относятся, если теоретический ответ на вопрос не будет диссертацией. Узкоспециализированные вопросы не очень приживаются, не оцениваются, не отвечаются. У них свои коммьюнити.

Comment: Вроде ещё было обсуждение на мете насчёт специализированных вопросов, которые требуют комплексных ответов (сам не нашёл, если кто найдёт, скиньте ссылку в комментарии). Там в общем, пришли к тому что на такие вопросы мало кто отвечает и пользователи больше выбирают простые вопросы на который легко ответить (это касается как практики, так и теории).

Comment: К интересным вам (судя по прочитанному мной) теоретическим темам, большинство тут отнесется плохо, поскольку в таких темах они толком не  разбираются, а вот смириться с этим фактом не могут. Тут время от времени появлялись волокущие люди, но столкнувшись с реальностью куда-то пропадали (очевидно не найдя соответствующей их уровню компании)

Comment: По факту закрывают как "невозможно дать объективный ответ" и минусуют все ответы. Я бы не стал задавать здесь непрактические вопросы, модераторы не приветствуют и закрывают.

Comment: Да вроде хорошо относятся. Открыл свои ответы, очень многие из них на чисто теоретические вопросы: [(1)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/197067/10105), [(2)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/505018/10105), [(3)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/416644/10105), [(4)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/235352/10105), [(5)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/486696/10105), ...

Answer (score 13):

Отвечу как в основном отвечающий :) — теоретические вопросы обычно отвечаемы, если отвечают (простите за каламбур) нескольким критериям.

Если вопрос слишком прост — такой, что достаточно полистать учебник/немного про*гугл*яться — он вызывает не желание ответить, а раздражение.

Вопросы глобальные — типа, как устроен компьютер или расскажите-ка мне о шаблонах С++ — как бы ни были интересны, не вызывают ни малейшего желания отвечать, потому что такой ответ, если он сделан всерьез — это уже как минимум студенческий реферат. Это надо долго и упорно колотить по клавишам — ради чего? Потому что вопроситель :) не смог сформулировать вопрос более точно (и интересно)?

Хороший теоретический вопрос (imho) — это вопрос, ответ на который не слишком длинный и не займет час времени, который достаточно узок, ясно сформулирован (увы, чтоб правильно задать вопрос — надо знать половину ответа...) и желательно нетривиален (чтоб не возникало желание просто отправить читать учебник для 5 класса... особенно хорошо, если в теме есть какие-то неочевидные тонкости, которыми хочется поделиться).

Ну, а идеальный вопрос — это хороший вопрос, который попадается на глаза, когда у отвечающего есть время для ответа и соответствующее настроение :)

P.S. Вот классический [пример вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1423648/195342), на который совершенно не хочется (да и невозможно) отвечать...

Comment: ну хз, мои вопросы - и не простые, и не обобщенные. В том же вопросе про микроядро я сделал упор именно на часть с файловой системой - как ядру загрузить программу/драйвер [которые по идее лежат в ФС в случае с микроядром], не имея изначально файловой системы. Ну про magic mount от Magisk и патчинг Magisk-ом SELinux - тут даже не знаю, какая может быть конкретика. Четкий и направленный вопрос...

Comment: @RandomDice779 Не будучи специалистом в этой области, мне трудно ответить на ваш конкретный вопрос о конкретном вопросе...

Comment: @RandomDice779, для вопросов, как про микроядро, заведите тут чат ([как этот](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26298/c-c)) и делайте в новых вопросах ссылки туда. Может и соберется компания

Comment: прочитал обновление вашего ответа. Конечно, такую банальщину нет никакого смысла задавать на SO, для этого есть гугл. Я же изначально имел в виду те теоретические вопросы, которые я задавал на SO - т е действительно сложные теоретические вопросы

Answer (score 3):

Рассмотрим общую трактовку и специальную.

**Что такое "хороший" вопрос ?**

Хороший вопрос заставляет задуматься, приводит к новому открытию, бросает вызов существующим взглядам в увлекающей и поддерживающей манере.

Хороший вопрос направлен на ядро, ключевой, узловой момент истории или ситуации.

Хороший вопрос приводит к глубоко значимым для человека ответам, и усиливает желание человека продолжать беседу.

Хороший вопрос должен захватить воображение адресата, чтобы тот был готов двинуться исследовать неведомое, невзирая на сопутствующую этому тревогу.

**После этого мое мнение про хороший теоретический (фундаментальный) вопрос:**

1. Это основа для применения в различных областях и технологиях;
2. Теоретический (фундаментальный) метод решает практическую задачу с использованием технических критериев (быстро, точно, эффективно и т.д.);
3. Приведенный практический пример (код, алгоритм, схема) показывает использование теоретического метода;
4. Плюсы и минусы рассмотренного метода для решения практических задач;
5. Интересен аудитории данного форума.